# Max Zoom Level in Mapnik

Tags: mapnik, rendering, zoom

A question regarding [mapnik](http://mapnik.org/):

**Is it possible to configure a custom max. zoom level?** I am trying to find a way to get mapnik to render tiles for zoom levels 20+ (till 28 would be nice).

PS: The solution according to this [link](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/16037/how-to-render-high-zoom-level-maps-with-renderd) does not seem to exist anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know Mapnik is not what you need to configure here but whatever software you use to call Mapnik's rendering. In the link of yours it is renderd.